# Como acessar controls de um formGroup que está dentrou de um FormArray

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Galera, tenho um formulário criado com o formBuilder. Este formulário é composto por uma estrutura que possui array dentro de array.

Meu formulário:

```
export class RoteiroAddForm extends FormComponent<any>{

  constructor(private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    super(formBuilder.group({}))
  }

  roteiroTeste = this.formBuilder.group({
    dadosGerais: this.formBuilder.group({
      nomeRoteiro: [''],
      sistema: [''],
      casouso: [''],
      requisitante: [''],
      gerenteProjeto: [''],
    }),
    cenarios: this.formBuilder.array([
      this.formBuilder.group({
        nomeCenario: [''],
        casosTestes: this.formBuilder.array([
          this.formBuilder.group({
            nomeCasoTeste: [''],
            descricao: [''],
            preCondicao: this.formBuilder.array([
              this.formBuilder.group({
                descricaoPreCondicao: [''],
              })
            ]),
            resultadoEsperado: [''],
            procedimentos: this.formBuilder.array([
              this.formBuilder.group({
                criterioProcedimento: [''],
                descricaoPassoProcedimento: ['']
              }),
              this.formBuilder.group({
                descricaoVerificacaoProcedimento: [''],

              })
            ]),
            posCondicao: ['']
          })
        ])
      })
    ])
  })
```

Eu não estou conseguindo acessar o meu formControlName: nomeCenario que está dentro o array de cenarios.

Meu metódo de inclusão de cenário:

```
incluirCenario() {

    this.cenario.nome = this.roteiroAddForm.nomeCenario;
    this.cenarios.push({ ...this.cenario })

  }
```

O meu HTML está assim:

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="roteiroAddForm.roteiroTeste">
      <form [formGroup]="roteiroAddForm.roteiroTeste">

        <div formArrayName="cenarios">
          <ng-template matStepLabel>Cenários / Casos de teste</ng-template>
          <mat-card>
            <mat-card-title>Cadastrar Cenário</mat-card-title>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width:40%">
              <mat-label>Nome do Cenário:</mat-label>
              <input matInput type="text" formControlName="nomeCenario" maxlength="100" />
            </mat-form-field>

            <!--[disabled]="!roteiroAddForm.nomeCenario"-->
            <button mat-button (click)="incluirCenario(cenario)" color="primary">Incluir
              <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </mat-card>

        </div>
      </form>
```

Eu preciso de alguma maneira pegar a informação do formControlName= nomeCenario para o array de cenários, já tentei de diversas maneiras e não estou conseguindo pegar o valor passado no input;

Erro apresentado:

```
RoteiroAddComponent.html:66 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'cenarios -> nomeCenario'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certo, dentro do seu component você pode criar um get

```
 get formControlCompanies(): FormArray { return <FormArray>this.roteiroTeste .get('cenarios'); }
```

onde você precisar chamar você vai usar

```
formControlCompanies.invalid, etc...
```

no html ficaria mais ou menos assim

```
<div class="form-box_scroll_company mt-3" formArrayName="cenarios">
               <div class="row" *ngFor="let formItemCenarios of formControlCompanies.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
```

e pra acessar em outros lugares algum item ficaria assim, acessar o nome dentro do formArray direto:

```
formControlName="nomeItem"
```

tem outras abordagens também,

```
formItemCenarios.formGroup['controls']['name'].errors
```